# Typescript: encode the arithmetic operation

Tags: angular, typescript

In my angular2 with typescript, I am trying to send an arithmetic operation like `2+4` with http get, and the back-end must answer `6`.

Currently, the `+` is considered as `space` so in back end i recieve `2 4` so the operator is missed.

How can i encode my query to deliver it precisely in back-end?

Here is my http get sender service:

```
@Injectable()
export class HttpService {

  constructor(private http:Http) { }
  getAnswer(par:string){
    const query=par;
    console.log("value is:"+par);
   return  this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/?question='+query).map((res)=>res.text());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use `encodeURIComponent` javaScript function.

```
return this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/?question='+ encodeURIComponent(query)).map((res)=>res.text());
```

Then on your back-end, you need to decode the query string to get the decoded value.